# ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found -ruamel

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I am trying to create an azure function to call a machine learning model (pkl file) stored in azure blob. the requirements.txt looks like this

azure-functions
ipython
optuna
openpyxl
hyperopt
seaborn
pandas
numpy
lime
sklearn
shap==0.34.0
xgboost
azureml-core

```
   import logging
   import azure.functions as func
  from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment, Run, Datastore,Dataset
  def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
  name = req.params.get('name')
  if not name:
   try:
      req_body = req.get_json()
      except ValueError:
      pass
  else:
    name = req_body.get('name')

  if name:
  return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
  else:
  return func.HttpResponse(
     "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the 
     request body for a personalized response.",
     status_code=200
   )
```

executing  pip install ruamel.yaml

```
     Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\emphr\lib\site- 
    packages (0.16.12)
    Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml.clib>=0.1.2 in
```

could you please let me know why i am getting the module not found error.

Thanks